# Transforming variable to match the distribution of another

Tags: data-transformation

I'm training a logistic regression on data that is a proxy for the actual data I intent to use for predictions (due to constraints outside my control, I don't have response values for the testing dataset).

The distribution of one of the predictor variables in the training data is substantially different from the testing dataset, as shown in the chart below.

[image]

However, this is due to covariate shift, and if we were to use this predictor as defined in the training data, our model would systematically underperform. In other words, the predictor's distribution in the testing dataset reflects the new reality, and the training version should reflect this.

**Is there a method to transform the predictor's distribution to match the one in the testing dataset?**